# Best approach to keep java and groovy classes

Tags: java, maven, groovy

What is the best approach for keeping java and groovy classes in project structure?

Should I have separate directory tree for java classes and groovy classes (both for src and test) or better keep the classes in one directory tree?

What are the pros and cons for both approaches?

What will be better when it comes to maintenance?

P.S. I compile groovy classes using Maven.

Comment: I've never written a project with mixed sources but I'd definitely try  to keep the sources separately for better readability.

Comment: Currently we work on a project with mixed sources in same directory tree. We see no difference at all.

Comment: I asked because sometimes I add single additional class written in groovy for xml parsing and so on (but all package is written in java) and one class in separate package and path looks weird... That's why I asked about pros and cons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using maven,

```
src/
|->main/
   |->java/
   |->groovy/
|->test/
   |->java/
   |->groovy/
```

Wouldn't this be a good approach?

I left out other obvious maven artifacts like pom.xml etc.

**EDIT:**
Maintenance is easiest when you have the source code separately for different programming languages. Easy to carry on build s and all software configuration management tasks.
However I don't see any advantage of having all the source code in a single tree hierarchy.

Comment: It seems good an obvious. I suppose that OP was rather asking about potential problems and drawbacks of such approach.

Comment: @Opal Made changes to the answer

Comment: One thing worth pointing out: if you do this, you _should_ have at least one .java class to make all the Eclipse people happy. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven#Groovy-EclipsecompilerpluginforMaven-Donothing